# SQL Server - Generate unique ID to compare several columns altogether

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, sql-server-2014, guid

In SQL Server, is it possible to generate a GUID using a specific piece of data as an input value. For example,

```
DECLARE @seed1 VARCHAR(10) = 'Test'
DECLARE @seed1 VARCHAR(10) = 'Testing'
SELECT NEWID(@seed1) -- will always return the same output value
SELECT NEWID(@seed2) -- will always return the same output value, and will be different to the example above
```

I know this completely goes against the point of GUIDs, in that the ID would not be unique. I'm looking for a way to detect duplicate records based on certain criteria (the @seed value).

I've tried generating a `VARBINARY` string using the `HASHBYTES` function, however joining between tables using `VARBINARY` seems extremely slow. I'm hoping to find a similar alternative that is more efficient.

**Edit**: for more information on why I'm looking to achieve this.

I'm looking for a fast and efficient way of detecting duplicate information that exists on two tables. For example, I have first name, last name & email. When these are concatenated, should can be used to check whether these records eexists in table A and table B.

Simply joining on these fields is possible and provides the correct result, however is quite slow. Therefore, I was hoping to find a way of *transforming* the data into something such as a GUID, which would make the joins much more efficient.

Comment: It seems you have decided on a way to do something and are now asking for help on how to do that one specific thing.  Could you please add some dummy data representative of your situation and a desired output?  It is very likely a simpler solution is available

Comment: *I'm looking for a way to detect duplicate records based on certain criteria*, can you expand on this requirement? This might be an XY problem.

Comment: A GUID is effectively a `BINARY(16)`, and just about as slow to join on. When hashing, your `VARBINARY` values may end up bigger, but that can be "solved" by taking a substring (at the expense of increased collision probability, but that's not an issue for a proper cryptographic hash). If the results are still too big/slow, you're better off using an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` on a lookup table, with the drawback that these need to be synchronized across callers, but this is usually offset by the vastly better performance you get when joining on 4-byte integers.

Comment: Now you've explained why you want it, I'd say the CHECKSUM or HASHBYTES functions would be exactly what you'd need; they're specifically designed for exactly the purpose you have in mind. (Note that there's some tiny possibility of two different items summing to the same value, so you should probably keep your original matching criteria, but as long as the checksum value is indexed and used in your queries *as well*, SQL Server should be smart enough to use that index to filter down the results before doing the exact comparison.) What you're looking for is definitely a "hash", conceptually.

Comment: If you merely want to speed up joins, you don't even need your shorter values to be unique -- it's sufficient for them to be *unique enough* to speed up index searches (`WHERE hash1 = hash2 AND mycolumn1 = mycolumn2`, where the first part will allow most of the speedup). Even `CHECKSUM` works for this purpose, although its collision rates are terrible for a lot of real-world data, and you can be better off with (say) `CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(HASHBYTES(...), 1, 4))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use **CHECKSUM** function for returning int type.

Comment: I agree with you, but i'd show an example of this for the OP.

Comment: `checksum` is far too prone to collisions for this purpose.  Microsoft themselves advise against using `checksum` for this.

Comment: For what I needed, `CHECKSUM` was ideal. I had to include other criteria on a join to avoid the potential collisions, but this was still faster than joining on two `HASHBYTES` columns.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `hashbytes` and not `checksum` like this:

```
SELECT hashbytes('MD5', 'JOHN' + ',' + 'SMITH' + ',' + 'JSMITH@EXAMPLE.COM')
```

Although it's only a small chance checksum can produce the same number with 2 completely different values, I've had it happen with datasets of around a million.  As iamdave noted (thanks!), it's a good idea to throw in some kind delimiter (a comma in my example) so that you don't compare `'JOH' + 'NSMITH'` and `'JOHN' + 'SMITH'` as the same.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/microsoft-business-intelligence-and-data-warehousing/2012/02/01/checksum-vs-hashbytes/

Comment: Well, it's not *that* small... `SELECT CHECKSUM('--a--'), CHECKSUM('a')`. Aside from this weirdness, `CHECKSUM` has worse collision rates than just about anything else you could use. The only saving grace is that, as long as your index is not `UNIQUE` (and it shouldn't be, as that's just asking for trouble), you can suffer plenty of collisions before performance starts to go down noticeably.

Comment: it is worth noting that a delimiter should added between values.  `'John' + 'Smith'` will give the same `hashbytes` output as `'Joh' + 'nSmith'`